# Subscribe call within a forEach loop executes too late

Tags: javascript, if-statement, foreach

Why does the console log show all the "if" output at the end?

```
3 elem :
else
elem :
else
elem :
else
elem :
else
2 elem :
4 if
```

I expected the output :

```
elem
if 
elem 
else ...
```

I thought that it would show "if" or "else" right after every "elem"!

Here is the code :

```
res.docs.forEach((elem) => {
    console.log('elem');
    if (elem.productType) {
        this.Service.function(elem.productType._id).subscribe((result) => {
            console.log('if');
            const text = result.name;
            this.marketPlaceList.push(text);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('else');
        this.marketPlaceList.push('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Totally depends on the content of `res.docs`, not shown in the post, though. Also, if `Service` is an async ... Wait! Does `Service` have a method named `function`..?

Comment: post what is inside `res.docs`

Comment: `.subscribe()` is probably an asynchronous function

Comment: You have to get the `console.log('if');` out of the async response, or else all the `forEach` loop is ended when it starts logging them

Comment: I'm sorry I thought that it will be clear .. Ok 
Service is an angular Service.
and function is a function inside the service.

yes it s an async function

Comment: note, your `this.marketPlaceList` array will be in an order you wont expect

Comment: The async part is the problem. As you can see by the output your if cases which are async are handled after all the other cases. As @JaromandaX said the `this.marketPlaceList`will be in an order you wont expect, this problem is also caused by your async design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an observable emits events asynchronously, your `forEach` loop will have finished before any callback to `.subscribe` is executed.

You could solve this by turning the observable to a promise, and `await`-ing it. For `await` to work, you need an `async` function, so wrap your code into such a function, and change the `forEach` loop into a `for` loop:

```
(async () => { // Async wrapper
    for (const elem of res.docs) { // Use for-loop
        console.log('elem');
        if (elem.productType) {
            // Convert observable to promise, and await
            const result = await this.Service.function(elem.productType._id).toPromise();
            console.log('if');
            const text = result.name;
            this.marketPlaceList.push(text);
        } else {
            console.log('else');
            this.marketPlaceList.push('');
        }
    }
)(); // execute immediately
```

Be sure to also await the outermost `async` function (or use `then` on it) when you need the `this.marketPlaceList` array to be completely populated.